# mysql_fetch_array returning false

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$method = $_POST["method"]; //dropdown box
$category = $_POST["category"]; //dropdown box
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$companyname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["companyname"]);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["state"]);
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["zip"]);

$salt = $email;
$length = 10;
$temporarypassword =  
substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),  
0, $length);
$temp_encrypted_password = sha1($salt.$temporarypassword);

$addcompany = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company (`method`, `category`,  
`email`, `password`, `companyname`, `phone`, `address`, `state`, `zip`, `ratingcount`, 
`ratingscore`, `usage`, `date`)
VALUES 
('$method','$category','$email','$temp_encrypted_password',
'$companyname','$phone','$address','$state','$zip','0','0','0',CURDATE()) ")
or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_fetch_array($addcompany)) {

$to = "$email";
$subject = "Your Temporary Password";
$message = "Your temporary password is: <b>$temporarypassword;</b>. Sign in and   
update your password as soon as possible.";
$header = "From: email@gmail.com\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

$message = "Company Added";

}

}
}
```

So, the sql statement executes just fine and is entered into my database just as I want it. However, the IF statement for if $addcompany returns true must be returning false, because nothing inside the statement executes. I use this check for mysql_fetch_array this way on other parts of my site and it works fine so I'm curious as to why it isn't returning in this case.

FYI I'm looking into PDO for those who will say it. lol I already got reamed for it on a previous post today.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: You perform an insert so there is nothing to "fetch"

Comment: ah ya know what, that's right. I use this elsewhere, but it's for select statements. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: What if you try to use `or Die(mysql_error())` outside your `if` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php-doku declares, that for all INSERT-statements [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php) returns a boolean, whether the statement was successfully executed.
So you don't need to

```
if (mysql_fetch_array($addcompany)) {
```

But simply

```
if ($addcompany) {
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array isn't meant to be used in an if condition for inserts, but in a while loop for **select** statements which will go through each result of your query. If there's no result, then the script won't enter the loop.

Check the examples at the bottom of php.net : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You just need `if ($addcompany) {` here, no fetch_array